# Why wasn't Hunter x Hunter chapter 350 released yet?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

Does anyone here know why Hunter x Hunter chapter 350 has not been released yet?

When is it coming out? I would be grateful for any answers or comments you are able to provide.